# Finding id of appended li in bxslider in php

Tags: jquery, wordpress, bxslider

I am using bxslider in wordpress.I am appending li's relative to the id of selected li. But I am unable to find out the id of the li which I am appending. I have to find out the id of the li being selected of appended li so that I can append further li's as the li which I will be selecting from the slider the next slide will appear relative to that li.

I am pasting my code below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
/* autoControls: true, */
mode: 'horizontal',
slideWidth: 800,
slideMargin: 10,
nextSelector: '#slider-next',
prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
nextText: '<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/next.png" />',
prevText:'<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/back.png" />'
}); 

$('.bxslider li div a').click(function(){
var id = this.id;
//alert(id);

if(id=='slide1'){ 
$(this).siblings().remove();

$('.bxslider').append('<li><div class="caption" style="float:left;"><a id="slide6" class="effect" onclick="myslide(this.id)" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/12.png" onclick="myimage(this.id)" id="1" alt="image01"/><span style="display:inline">Full Color 11"X17" Posters</span></a></div><div class="caption" style="float:left;"><a class="effect" id="slide7" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/12.png" onclick="myimage(this.id)" id="1" alt="img05"/><span style="display:inline">Full Color 18"X24" Posters</span></a></div></li>');
slider.reloadSlider();

}
}
```

Please let me know how to find the id of the appended li.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:last` selector to target last element:

```
$('.bxslider li:last').attr('id')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not working in my application.

Comment: Next and previous buttons of the slider disappeared after adding this to my code. I put it below:- $('.bxslider li div a').click(function() .